# Java: Calling println From Outside Main Method

Tags: java, methods, println

So I am creating a very basic airport simulator for my Java Programming class in school. I need to print a message to the console every time I call the method fly() or land() and was just curious on the most practical way to do this. I would choose to make it a void method and so each time it is called from the main method it just prints right from fly(). I vaguely remember my professor telling me that this way is a bad practice and that you shouldn't print to the console from an outside method. Is this true? Would it be better to make the fly() and land() methods return a String and then print that out?

```
public void fly() {
    System.out.println("Plane is flying.");
}
```

OR

```
public String fly() {
    return "Plane is flying.";
}
```

Comment: There's no inherent bad practice to printing something from within a function. If you need to print output every time the plane is flying, put a `println` inside the `fly` function.

Comment: Real applications tend to write in files or print to logs. I will use this as analogy. That said, I see no reason you should do such actions only within method `main`. The name of your method(s), however, should reflect the fact that a message is printed. In the given case, one could wirte a method `public void printMessage(String s) { System.out.println(s); }` and call this method from within `fly()` and `land()`

Answer (score 1):

Your professor has a point; in actual development I'd be leveraging a logging framework to take the place of `System.out.println` here, but that's likely *not* what they're talking about...

Ultimately this depends on what you're doing.  If you want to *display* a value when you invoke `fly`, then you can use the first approach.  If you plan on *using* the value you get back when you invoke `fly`, you can use the second approach. **There is no value in the second approach if all you *ever* want to do is print a message.**

Without seeing how your methods intermingle with one another, making a blanket call is impossible.  You must choose the method and approach that makes the most sense for your application.

Answer (score 0):

In general, printing a message directly from a method is not a bad approach, but it depends on the context. Sometimes the domain logic (flying) should be separate from the logging (`System.out.println`). If you do not want to print the message directly in the `fly` method, you can create a second method that wraps the `fly` method and prints the desired message:

```
public void flyAndLog() {
    fly();
    System.out.println("Plane is flying.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a complicated way (had to write this answer hahaha)

```
public interface Status {
   Status next();
   Status previous(); 
   String representation();
}

public class PlaneLanding implements Status {
    private final Status previous;

    public PlaneLanding(Status previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    @Override
    public String representation() {
        return "Plane is landing";
    }

    @Override
    public Status next() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Status previous() {
        return previous;
    }
}

public class PlaneFlying implements Status {
    private final Status previous;

    public PlaneFlying(final Status previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    @Override
    public String representation() {
        return "Plane is flying";
    }

    @Override
    public Status next() {
        return new PlaneLanding(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Status previous() {
        return previous;
    }
}

class PlaneSimlulator {
   public static void main(final String... args) {
      Status planeStatus = new PlaneTakingOff();

      do {
         System.out.println(planeStatus.representation());
         planeStatus = planeStatus.next();
      } while (planeStatus != null);
   }
}
```